# How to know the cause of InterruptedException in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

How to know the thread A that interrupted the thread B that is throwing the `InterruptedException`?

Comment: I am facing a problem with thread B. It is always interrupted. I want to know the cause to be able to handle the problem

Comment: What threads have access to thread B? You'll need to provide more details. The short answer is: you can't.

Comment: If you are calling `interrupt()` yourself, you can put breakpoints on those calls

Comment: The application that I have is a very big multithreaded application. So I have around 60 threads are executed.

Comment: What does "it is always interrupted" mean?  Is it by design? or is the source of the interrupts a mystery?  If it's by design, and your thread B (the interrupted thread) needs to know the reason for the interrupt, then it's up to you to communicate that information from thread A (the interrupting thread) to thread B.  For example, thread A could set a variable that it shares with thread B before it delivers the interrupt.

Comment: If the source of the interrupt is a mystery, but you suspect one of the other threads, then how about running the program in a debugger, and setting a breakpoint on Thread.interrupt()?

Comment: `jvisualvm` may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you could not know which thread triggers the interrupt.

It is kind of status flag, that's it. No matter `InterruptedException` or `isInterrupted()`, there is no extra information provided.

Further, if you need to cooperate threads in finer grade, try other ways.